# UICollectionViewCell becomes visible on scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` which holds seven `UICollectionViewCells` which are build with information coming from a plist file. When I start the App only four `UICollectionViewCells` are visible, until i start scrolling down - this makes the violett `UICollectionViewCell` visible (see in Screenshot). My question is, how I can display the fourth (violett) `UICollectionViewCell` on app start.

In `- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
 I am building and setting up the cells:

```
CategoryCollectionViewCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:catCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSString *plist = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mainCategories" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *plistArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plist];
NSDictionary *cat = [plistArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

CGFloat red = [[cat objectForKey:@"color_red"] doubleValue];
CGFloat green = [[cat objectForKey:@"color_green"] doubleValue];
CGFloat blue = [[cat objectForKey:@"color_blue"] doubleValue];
CGFloat alpha = [[cat objectForKey:@"color_alpha"] doubleValue];

UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:(red/255.0) green:(green/255.0) blue:(blue/255.0) alpha:1];
[cell setBackgroundColor:color];
cell.label_CategoryName = [cat objectForKey:@"text"];
cell.image_CategoryIcon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@",[cat objectForKey:@"image"], kImageExt]];

return cell;
```

[image]
Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand - do you want the violet cell to be visible together with the blue one or you want the initial scroll position to be such that the violet cell is visible?

Comment: As you can see in the first picture, there is a white space after the yellow cell - this is the space where the violett cell appears if I start scrolling.

Comment: Hmm strange. It wasn't apparent from the screenshot. Does it magically appear when you put your finger and start scrolling?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - just updated the screenshots!
Yes, once I start scrolling, the violett cell appears and everything is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the content insets of the collection view downwards incrementally, 1 point at a time, until it starts behaving the way you want it to.

```
[_collectionView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0)];
```

CellForRowAtIndex is fired many times and the following code...

```
NSString *plist = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mainCategories" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *plistArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plist];
NSDictionary *cat = [plistArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
```

Is building an entire new instance of your array in memory, each time.  This is very inefficient.  Considering instantiating your array once, maybe lazily in a property or in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Working fine - thank you! Building the array was just for testing purposes :-)